# MIPS case conversion problems

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm having some issues with a mips program that takes a string of letters and converts the lower case letter a to upper case letter a. I have most of it written but I cannot seem to figure out how to get my output to print the new string.

```
.data

str: .asciiz "abaaabaaabbbbccccdddaaddbaabbbabab \n\n"
prompt: .asciiz "Given String is = "
ans: .asciiz "Replaced String is = "



.text
.globl main
main:

la $a0, prompt
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, str
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, ans
li $v0, 4
syscall


la $t1, str
li $t5, 97


Loop:

lb $t0, 0($t1)
beqz $t0, StrEnd
bne $t0, $t5, nextletter 
addi $t0, $t0, -32
sb $t0, 0($t1)

nextletter:
addi $t0, $t0, 1

j Loop


StrEnd:

move $a0, $t1
li $v0, 1
syscall


li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: It depends how the MIPS chip and input/output peripherals are connected. Chip itself does not have I/O peripherals but inputs and outputs pins.

Comment: Thanks I got it figured out. I was using the wrong registers in my loop and forgot to call a string to print, instead I was printing a number.